# adding script to find min value to a for loop c#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, min

I am adding to my for loop to find min and max values in an array I am getting from parsing a text file. Finding the max value was easy enough, but for the min I am getting a value of zero where it should be 1. Here is what I am using for the loop- (I so far I am only testing to get the min of temp.x)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

        string line = dataLines [i];
        lineValues = line.Split (' ');

        Vector4 temp = new Vector4 ();
        Vector3 center = new Vector3 ();

        temp.x = float.Parse (lineValues [0]);

        maxvalueX = float.MinValue;
        minvalueX = float.MaxValue;

        if (temp.x > maxvalueX) { maxvalueX = temp.x; } 
        if (temp.x < minvalueX) { minvalueX = temp.x; }

        temp.y = float.Parse (lineValues [1]);
            if (temp.y > maxvalueY) { maxvalueY = temp.y; }

        temp.z = float.Parse (lineValues [2]);
            if (temp.z > maxvalueZ) { maxvalueZ = temp.z; }

        temp.w = float.Parse (lineValues [3]);

        data.myData [i].Set (scaleFactor*temp.x, scaleFactor*temp.y, scaleFactor*temp.z, temp.w);
        data.myData [i].Set (scaleFactor*temp.x, scaleFactor*temp.y, scaleFactor*temp.z, temp.w);
        //int value = data.myData [i].x;

        center.x = ((maxvalueX-1)/2);
        center.y = ((maxvalueY-1)/2);
        center.z = ((maxvalueZ-1)/2);

        data.dataCenter.Set (scaleFactor*center.x, scaleFactor*center.y, scaleFactor*center.z);
    }
```

any ideas on what is going wrong here would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
Jen

Comment: What are you initializing the min values to?  Typically you'd want to set them to something like `float.MaxValue`.  If you don't initialize them then they will be 0 by default, which is less than 1.  You'd have the same type of issue with max if all your values were negative, so it really should be initialized to something like `float.MinValue`.

Comment: Why you don't use dataLines.Min();  to get smallest one?

Comment: You need to place `maxvalueX = float.MinValue;` and `minvalueX = float.MaxValue;` before the loop to avoid resetting the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to find the minimum values is to do the opposite of what you did with the maximum values, i.e.

```
if (temp.x > maxvalueX) { maxvalueX = temp.x; } 
if (temp.x < minvalueX) { minvalueX = temp.x; }
```

Bear in min that if it's possible that the lowest value is above 0 or the highest value is below 0, leaving the max and min default values set to 0 will cause you problems. Before the loop you should set them up like this:

```
float maxvalueX = float.MinValue;
float minvalueX = float.MaxValue;
```

That way you can be sure the numbers will be reset no matter the value they encounter. Make sure you handle the case of their being no values to consider too.

---

UPDATE:

I've included a full updated version of your code with comments to demonstrate what I mean:

```
// These should be before the loop just to avoid resetting the max/min values
float maxvalueX = float.MinValue;
float minvalueX = float.MaxValue;

  for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {

    string line = dataLines [i];
    lineValues = line.Split (' ');

    Vector4 temp = new Vector4 ();
    Vector3 center = new Vector3 ();

    temp.x = float.Parse (lineValues [0]);
    if (temp.x > maxvalueX) { maxvalueX = temp.x; } 
    if (temp.x < minvalueX) { minvalueX = temp.x; }

    temp.y = float.Parse (lineValues [1]);
        if (temp.y > maxvalueY) { maxvalueY = temp.y; }

    temp.z = float.Parse (lineValues [2]);
        if (temp.z > maxvalueZ) { maxvalueZ = temp.z; }

    temp.w = float.Parse (lineValues [3]);

    data.myData [i].Set (scaleFactor*temp.x, scaleFactor*temp.y, scaleFactor*temp.z, temp.w);
    data.myData [i].Set (scaleFactor*temp.x, scaleFactor*temp.y, scaleFactor*temp.z, temp.w);
    //int value = data.myData [i].x;
}

// I've moved these out of the loop as they only use the final max/min values
    center.x = ((maxvalueX-1)/2);
    center.y = ((maxvalueY-1)/2);
    center.z = ((maxvalueZ-1)/2);

    data.dataCenter.Set (scaleFactor*center.x, scaleFactor*center.y, scaleFactor*center.z);
```

Comment: I have added this and it changes the min value to the max value- Thank you though!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally used `maxvalueX` in place of `minvalueX` somewhere? Easily done when copying and pasting lines.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had put the float maxvalueX = float.MinValue;
float minvalueX = float.MaxValue;  in the loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (minvalueX  < temp.x) 
{
  valueX = temp.x;
  minvalueX = valueX;
}
```